# Поддержка NET 4.5 на Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте, подскажите, будут ли работать программы на NET 4.5 в Windows XP? Можно ли установить 4.5 на XP или в сборке с программой включить необходимые библиотеки?

Answer (score 3):

В [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8z6watww.aspx) написано для .NET 4.5 нужно минимум Windows Vista SP2.